# Managing prerequisites with MEF and Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mef, caliburn.micro

Lets say I have a component with a number of smaller components which check prerequisites before the first one will be initialized. They are not dependent on one another so I don't care about order and would like them to run simultaneously. I am using MEF and Caliburn.Micro for presentation.

I thought about this setup:

```
class Big
{
    [ImportMany]
    public IEnumerable<IBigPrerequisite> Prerequisites {get; set;}
    public void Initialize(){...}
}
```

and

```
interface IBigPrerequisite
{
    public bool IsBusy {...}
    public bool Allow {...}
    public void StartChecking();
}
```

Now what I would like to accomplish with this is that the classes implementing `IBigPrerequisite` can open up a window (for example "File X was not found - this could lead to errors. Continue?") - this should be possible.

But I would only want one window to be visible at a time. How would I accomplish that besides just going synchronously?

EDIT - since the question seemed too vague

I need these Actions to run specifically before `Big` will be activated. Let's say we switch up the activation logic to something like this:

```
Big big; //we got this through Importing somewhere in composition
var allow = true;
var count = 0;
if(!pre.Any()) //no prerequisites, show window immediately
    windowManager.ShowWindow(big)
foreach(var pre in big.Prerequisities)
{
    pre.PropertyChanged += (s, args) => 
    {
        if(args.PropertyName == "IsBusy" && !pre.IsBusy) // if a prerequisite finished it's check
        {
            allow = allow && pre.Allow; //if one prerequisite says nay we could just return, actually...
            count++;
            if(count == big.Prerequisites.Count() && allow)
                windowManager.ShowWindow(big);
        }
    }
    pre.StartChecking();
}
```

Now, I explicitly want the classes implementing `IBigPrerequisite` to be able to open a window, but in case all prerequisites are met (no user interaction required) no window should be showing. I do not wish to open up a window for every class here.

I am looking for a way to, say, give the IBigPrerequisite (which should probably be called `IPrerequisiteViewModel` anyways) a property like `bool RequestsWindow {get;}` and have the View only created when a) the viewmodel requests it and b) no other prerequisite window is open at the time.

Note: the code here is for illustration only as I am not sure how to implement this behaviour yet. I am not experienced with these frameworks (and concepts) so if this question seems silly please bear with me.

Comment: What have you tried and didn't work, what is your exact problem: showing the dialog, doing it synchronously or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer this question myself detailing how I ended up solving this.

I made a `LoaderViewModel : Conductor<PropertyChangedBase>.Collection.OneActive, IChild<Shell>` and gave it a `Queue<PropertyChangedBase>`.

It has Show/HideWindow methods by traversing the Parent-Properties until it arrives at the Window-Level.

It has `Queue` and `Dequeue` methods. `Queue` is used when `PropertyChanged` is fired on a `RequestsView`-Property and calls `Dequeue` if there's either no `ActiveItem` or the `ActiveItem` is not marked as busy. `Dequeue` will activate a new item if there is one in the queue and then call `ShowWindow`, if there is no item it will call `HideWindow` instead.

The initial `HideWindow` is done in the `ViewAttached`-Event since if the window is hidden, CM seems to have some strange behaviour. Here, the parallel checking of the prerequisites is started and an event-handler registered similar to the one in the first post.

Sorry for being verbose, but the code has gotten a bit lengthy. If someone wants me to post it up write a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing concepts here.

Active view management in Caliburn.Micro is handled by the Conductor class. A Conductor-derived ViewModel can display a large number of Screen-derived ViewModels (or other Conductors). Available items are stored in the Items property.

You can find a much better description at "[Screens, Conductors and Composition](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition)"

MEF has nothing to do with the Conductors and the composition mechanism, although it can be used to pass a list of items to a conductor. You can define an [ImportMany] constructor parameter or public property that receives the Screens to display during initializations and store them in the conductor's Items property.

Using a constructor parameter is more elegant, as you won't have to copy the items from your property's setter to the Items property.

Finally, you shouldn't display messages when creating your views and viewmodels. This is something that should be left for a later step, eg. during the Activate method. The Conductors and MEF get the parts together and build the UI. Executing actions and talking to the user should be done only after the composition step has finished.

Comment: From reading through that article I think `Conductor<T>.Collection.OneActive` is what I am looking for, but I do not know how I would go about using it.

Comment: I used your tip with the Conductor as a starting point but I had find the solution myself so I couldn't accept your answer.